# Using Watir, how can I select a radio control using both name and value?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I receive in my function the **name** and the **status** (value) and with that i want to set one of the radio button.

I'm trying do do something like this but is not accepting

```
r = $browser.input(:name => number).parent.radio :value => status
r.set
```

the html of the radio buttons is this

```
<input id="1" type="radio" checked="checked" value="activo" name="b1" onclick="oncheckRadio();" tabindex="7">    
<input id="1" type="radio" value="inactivo" name="b1" onclick="oncheckRadio();" tabindex="8">
```

Comment: Your developers are producing invalid HTML, you have ID values that are not unique.. you should file a bug on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely following the business logic of this, but here's some abductive reasoning for you (a guess)

```
def set_radio_by_name_and_status(name, status)
    $browser.radio(:name => name, :status => status).set
end
```

However, both radio buttons are named "b1" so setting by name seems a little redundant. I presume you meant the name and status of the radio button.

Comment: Tanks, i didn't know that we can various elements inside the bracelets

Comment: @macwadu You can, as long as you use the => symbol and seperate with commas (you are basically providing a hash argument to the radio method)

Comment: Since those are also 'wired' to react to onclick, you may want to fire that event after setting them if the UI does not seem to be responding the same way it does when you interact with it manually.